# What exactly is wrong with page 14?

Tags: bug, status-completed, information-display, pagination

I noticed that [Page 14 of "newest questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=14&sort=newest&pagesize=15) seems to always show only half of the questions the other pages do.

So, just out of curiosity … What's up with that, SO devs?

Comment: Do you have the "Hide ignored tags" option selected on your profile (the "perfs" tab)?

Comment: @ChrisF Nope. And I have no ignored tags.

Comment: I can reproduce this, it also happens on page 7 with 30 items per page, always after 200 questions.

Comment: Reproduced by simply clicking the link: Chrome 14.0.835.202 shows five results.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment the link was originally - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=14&sort=newest` - so, if it depends on the page size, wouldn't necessarily show the problem

Comment: @ChrisF Indeed, my setting of a page size of 50 is not affected; adding `pagesize=15` results in 5 results, adding `pagesize=30` results in 10 results.

Comment: It must be an Easter egg. `:-)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno i would have assumed just that if it had been page 42 :p

Comment: Cache issue, as after navigating to different page and coming back it's fine..

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's interesting ... I feel like a couple of days ago, I tried just that to no avail.

Comment: Hmm... it behave really strange. First click - five results. Closing window, trying again - five results. Closing window, opening different page, closing and opening with the original link - 15 results as expected, and it keep being OK afterwards **even in different browsers** - so it's server cache issue..

Comment: @ShadowWizard Server cache issue tied to your user account? 'Cause I bet there's dozens of users hitting that page on every given second.

Comment: Yeah, for example key/value object where the key is the user ID, sitting in the global  cache.

Comment: SE Dev 1 to Dev 2: _Hey, they finally found that page 14 joke you coded 3 years ago!_

Comment: Reproduced on mobile. Following the link gives a page with only 4 questions.

Comment: We're aware of this, some recent tag engine internal changes are likely in play here. Marc's taking a look soon as he gets a chance.

Comment: @NickCraver Would be awesome if an in-depth explanation followed up here ;)

Comment: @vzw In depth explanation: `If ( page==14 ) { ... }`

Comment: @belisarius: That would be really a joke

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> So, just out of curiosity … What's up with that, SO devs?

Well, back in the day we used to use direct queries to SQL Server to build up the various question sort pages.

This worked fine for a while, and Smurfs were happy. However, slowly, over time we discovered that for our specific use SQL is just not fast enough.

I posted a question on theoretical CS that touches on the issue: [Data structure that allow efficient tag based lookups](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6405/data-structure-that-allow-efficient-tag-based-lookups)

Fast forward a few months, and we reimplemented a large amount of functionality we used to depend on SQL Server for, using in-memory structures.

These days, when you click on any tag or combination of tags or click on the top level Newest, Faq, Active, Votes or Featured tabs you hit the **TAG ENGINE OF DOOM**

This in-memory structure holds all of the information needed to provide the various question sorts and filters in **lightning** speed.

The *Tag Engine* contains many optimisations, one such optimisation is the ...

#### Block size in the query cache

When the tag engine is asked for all the questions on **page 14** with **page size 15**, we cache the results so subsequent queries do not need to traverse the tag engine.

But we are **tricky**.

Instead of simple caching results numbered 195 -> 210, we attempt to cache blocks of 200.

Since we perform caching in blocks of 200, hitting page **1** of any sort with a page size of **50** wil pre-fetch the next 3 pages.

But there was a bug.

The code that decided how many results we need to pre-fetched, was only fetching results **0** through **200**. Somebody (Waffles) forgot to allow for a misaligned block.

I just fixed the engine so it now will fetch **0** -> **400** in the example case.

#### And there was peace on earth...

<sub>or was there... fast forward a few months and we discovered that .NET is freezing our app once every few minutes for about a second, it does not like having so much stuff in memory ... the resolution of this is a topic of another post</sub>

Comment: Very interesting and a lot of details. +1 !

Comment: I'm rather surprised it didn't take you 6-8 weeks to fix it :D +1!

Comment: @waffles - Is the resolution of that secondary problem the topic of another post you've made, or the topic of a post you'll hypothetically make later?

Comment: @KevinVermeer I plan to blog about it

Comment: Doesn't a block size of 400 just shift the problem to page 28 (with page size 15)?  Would a block size of 300 (evenly divisible by 15, 30 and 50) be better?

Comment: @freiheit ... it actually extends the fetch size by 200 till there is full cover

Comment: in general nobody visits page 14 ... it is possible that a block size of 100 would actually be more effective