# Question not in newest questions after 19 hours

Tags: bug, information-display, pagination, newest-questions

The following question was asked 19 hours ago (as of when the meta question was asked), but isn't appearing in the "Newest questions" for [java](/questions/tagged/java) from that time period.

Here's the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925666/installing-jnlp-on-ubuntu-for-open-jdk-7), showing that it was asked 19 hours ago
[image: My question]

Here's the "Newest question" feed for [java](/questions/tagged/java) for the corresponding period. It contains questions asked 18 to 20 hours ago, but not mine. The URL for this screenshot was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?page=10&sort=newest&pagesize=50

[image: Newest question feed]

My question hasn't been downvoted into oblivion, or closed, and I don't have Stack Overflow configured to hide questions in my ignored list.

The question is only on page 10. If I have 50 questions per page, does page 10 turn into my [page <s>14</s> 28](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109528/what-exactly-is-wrong-with-page-14)?

Currently, it only has 10 views. I don't know whether that's because it never appeared on the [java](/questions/tagged/java) newest question feed, or was a boring question.

Comment: Of note, listen to the latest podcast. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/podcast-59-hes-one-of-those-science-ists/ (this is somewhere around 30:00)

Comment: Yeah, as for that podcast, *"Users that are relatively trusted by the system get more impressions on the front page for their questions. **If you have a couple hundred reputation** and you seem like a trusted user, your question gets more eyeballs."* There you go Andrew, lose some reputation already ;-)